# d3 enter/exit pattern with array of objects

Tags: d3.js

I want to create a very simple `<ul>` list with d3 bounded data.

The data is in array of objects in the form of:

`[0 => {title: "title one"}, 1=> {title: "title two"}]`

My code so far:

```
var titles = _.findWhere(scope.titles, {key: d.key}).values;
var li = d3.select('.overview-popup ul').selectAll('li')
  .data(titles);

li.enter()
  .append('li')
  .text(function(n){ return n.title });

li.exit().remove();
```

The result of this is not as I would predict, where the `li` elements get `cleaned` every time a new data array is fed to it. It will leave some nodes and update depending on the number of nodes. Is this because of the index?

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wq8zocmy/)

Comment: So from my understanding, d3 joins the new data to the existing data array. I'm still not certain how the key function fixes this. I'm running into the same issue. When I use the key function, nothing shows up on my graph and so I need a better understanding of the key function I guess. I'm using an array like this `[{ date: 'some date...', percent: '2.89' }]` the dates are consistent between new arrays with a certain range and percents are unknown. I would really like to use the default index because the objects are in order but when I do that and pull new data, the graph points dont update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

> To achieve object constancy with D3.js, specify a key function as the second argument to selection.data

(from [Object Constancy - Key Functions)](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions)

In your case it would be:

```
var li = d3.select('.overview-popup ul')
           .selectAll('li')
           .data(titles, function(e) { return e.title });
```